# create a dynamicllay calender in code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, calendar

Hi all how can i build this code from a aspx page in a code behind Dynamically

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate1" Width = "150px" runat="server" Enabled="True" />
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtStartDate1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: what is the problem with my post? :)

Comment: Where did I say there was a problem with your post? Did you read the link I posted? Did you even look at the URL?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox txtDate = new TextBox();
txtDate.ID = "txtStartDate1";
txtDate.Width = "150px";
txtDate.Enabled = true;

CalendarExtender calExt= new CalendarExtender();
calExt.ID = "CalendarExtender1";
calExt.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
calExt.TargetControlId = txtStartDate1;

SomeParentControl.Controls.Add(txtDate);
SomeParentControl.Controls.Add(calExt);
```

This is what you wanted? Either way, these are the very basics of asp.net. You should try to read some tuts, watch videos etc.. In other words - learn and show some effort of yours...